# How to Arrange a Figure in center of page using full width of page while using IEEEtran in LaTex?

Tags: latex

I am using Overleaf and used the IEEEtran template to write my paper. I want to show a figure to full page width and in the center of the page. But the two-column template is not allowing me to do this. The Code of my figure is given below. I limited the sizes of images according to one side of the template so please ignore that.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]

\begin{tabular}{c c c} 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Case 1}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0008_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0008_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Case 2}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0009_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0009_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Case 3}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0012_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0012_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Case 4}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0013_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0013_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Case 5}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0018_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0018_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Case 6}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0019_Footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{exp_0019_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textit{\textbf{Final Ensemble Output Case}}}\\
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{Result_SAR.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{ensembled_footprint.png} & 
\includegraphics[height = 1.2in ,width = 1.2in]{ensembled_polygons_900x900.png}\\ 

\end{tabular}
\caption{Experiments Results and Polygons}
\label{Experiments Results and Polygons}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] including a documentclass and the necessary packages

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `figure*` environment instead of `figure`. The other part of your code can remain the same.
Normally, in IEEE Transactions, it is preferred to have the `[t]` label of the table to put it on the top of the page.

> By the way, you can get a quicker answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com.

Another point is that you can use `\subfloat` command in `subfig` package instead of using `tabular`.